# What is a equivalent for GetDC() function when Device Context is a printer

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ce

I try to write some code which is responsibility to draw a signal on printer context device.
Application is created for WindCE 2013 in VS2013.
This is a way for create DC:

```
extern TCHAR DriverName[256];
    extern TCHAR DeviceName[256];
    extern TCHAR OutputName[256];
    ZeroMemory(&psd, sizeof(psd));
    psd.lStructSize = sizeof(psd);
    psd.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    psd.hDevMode = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevMode.
    psd.hDevNames = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevNames.
    psd.Flags = PSD_INTHOUSANDTHSOFINCHES | PSD_MARGINS;
    psd.rtMargin.top = 1000;
    psd.rtMargin.left = 1250;
    psd.rtMargin.right = 1250;
    psd.rtMargin.bottom = 1000;
    if (PageSetupDlg(&psd) == TRUE)
    {
        memcpy(&dm, (DEVMODE *)(psd.hDevMode), sizeof(DEVMODE));
        lstrcpy(DriverName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDriverOffset)));
        lstrcpy(DeviceName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDeviceOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        hDC = CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, &dm);
    }
    return TRUE;
```

I draw each point in loop, but I have a problem because if I don't use a ReleaseDC() or DeleteDC() function, execution takes too long time. Memory is geting full and drawing new points is very slow.
I solved this problem for display context very easily by put on start of loop GetDC() function and ReleaseDC() on its end. (Code below)

```
    for (int k = 0, offset = 40; k <= kanal; k++, offset += 33)
    {
        float czasy[12];
        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;
        HPEN CzerwonePioro, Pudelko;
        POINT stary;
        do
        {
            hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
            //hDC = CDC;
            int x, y1, y2;
            float speed = 0.22;
            int test = memECG[1][i];
            DWORD error;
            CzerwonePioro = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, 0x000000);
            Pudelko = (HPEN)SelectObject(hDC, CzerwonePioro);
            //y2 = tab[i - 1];
            MoveToEx(hDC, speed*j, offset - 0.02*memECG[k][i - 1], NULL);
            LineTo(hDC, speed*j + 1, offset - 0.02*memECG[k][i]);
            SelectObject(hDC, Pudelko);
            i++;
            j += 1;
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
        } while (i < 1000);

    }
```

For printer I tried to use GetCompatibleDC or CreateDC in function but it doesn't work.
Have you any idea how to release printer DC and in next iteration use same DC (for time and memory safe) ?

Comment: Have you read [Printer Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printer-output)? "Unlike a display DC, a printer DC is not owned by the window management component, and it cannot be obtained by calling the GetDC function. Instead, an application must call the CreateDC or PrintDlgEx function."

Comment: I edit my post to show You how I create DC

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/retrieving-a-printer-device-context

Comment: That's not possible.  Fix the bugs instead of trying to hide them.  Start with the memory leak caused by creating the pen and never destroying it.  Hoist CreatePen() out of the loop, DeleteObject() after it.  You may have to reduce the number of LineTo() calls.

Comment: @HansPassant 
In my opinion is not possible to reduce LineTo() calls because number of LineTo() is corresponding with number of signal samples

Comment: While that is possible, it generally results in poor print quality. Though most printers are raster devices, some aren't (commonly called "plotters"). The whole purpose of a device context is to abstract those differences behind a common interface. The canonical solution here is to simply create a printer DC, and re-purpose your window-rendering code to draw into that. This usually gets you a visual representation at the target device' resolution.

Comment: You need to read about [Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) to understand, what they are, and why they are there.

Comment: @HansPassant is correct, you should only create the pen once here.  You should also only need to call `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` once also, before the loop - and after respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

> Memory is geting full and drawing new points is very slow.

You use `CreatePen` in the while loop to continuously create GDI objects, and you don't use `CreatePen` to destroy the objects after use. This will cause memory leaks, and if enough GDI objects are created, it will take up memory and affect the efficiency of the program.

> Have you any idea how to release printer DC and in next iteration use
> same DC (for time and memory safe) ?

You don't need to create DC repeatedly, you only need to use `CreateDC` to create device context once, and you can draw what you need in it.

Modified code:

```
    extern TCHAR DriverName[256];
    extern TCHAR DeviceName[256];
    extern TCHAR OutputName[256];
    ZeroMemory(&psd, sizeof(psd));
    psd.lStructSize = sizeof(psd);
    psd.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    psd.hDevMode = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevMode.
    psd.hDevNames = NULL; // Don't forget to free or store hDevNames.
    psd.Flags = PSD_INTHOUSANDTHSOFINCHES | PSD_MARGINS;
    psd.rtMargin.top = 1000;
    psd.rtMargin.left = 1250;
    psd.rtMargin.right = 1250;
    psd.rtMargin.bottom = 1000;
    if (PageSetupDlg(&psd) == TRUE)
    {
        memcpy(&dm, (DEVMODE *)(psd.hDevMode), sizeof(DEVMODE));
        lstrcpy(DriverName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDriverOffset)));
        lstrcpy(DeviceName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wDeviceOffset)));
        lstrcpy(OutputName, ((TCHAR *)((BYTE *)psd.hDevNames + ((DEVNAMES *)psd.hDevNames)->wOutputOffset)));
        hDC = CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, &dm);
        
        ...
        int x, y1, y2;
        float speed = 0.22;
        int test = memECG[1][i];
        DWORD error;
        float czasy[12];
        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;
        HPEN CzerwonePioro, Pudelko;
        POINT stary;
        CzerwonePioro = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, 0x000000);
        Pudelko = (HPEN)SelectObject(hDC, CzerwonePioro);
        for (int k = 0, offset = 40; k <= kanal; k++, offset += 33)
        {          
           do
           {
               MoveToEx(hDC, speed*j, offset - 0.02*memECG[k][i - 1], NULL);
               LineTo(hDC, speed*j + 1, offset - 0.02*memECG[k][i]);           
               i++;
               j += 1;
               
           } while (i < 1000);
           
        }
        SelectObject(hDC, Pudelko);
        DeleteObject(CzerwonePioro);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);              
    }
    return TRUE;
```